# Headings with non standard counting and without indentation. How?

Tags: sectioning

I would like to format the heading so they appear as depicted below. But I am stuck.

[image]

So far I have:

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode


\documentclass[11pt, oneside, ngerman]{report}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[center]{titlesec}

 
\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{Part\ \thepart}{0pt}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\part} 
  {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
  
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} 
  {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
  
\titleformat{\section}[display]
    {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\section} 
  {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
  
\titleformat{\subsection}[display]
    {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\subsection} 
  {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
  
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[display]
    {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection} 
  {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}


\titleclass{\part}{straight}
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}



\begin{document}


\renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\alph{subsubsection})}

\part*{First Part: Test Paaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaart}

\bigskip


\chapter{A. Test Chapter}

\bigskip


\section{I. Test Section}

\bigskip


\subsection{1. Test Subsection}

\bigskip


\subsubsection{a) Test Subsubsection}

\bigskip

{\lipsum[1-3]}
\end{document}
```

What gives me:

[image]

It would be great if they could count in their given scheme, be multiple lines long and be correctly indented, and appear in the toc like this(without extra numbering).

Edit:
I successfully changed the counting methods:

```
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\alph{subsubsection})}
```

But they won't display before the names of their headings

Thanks in advance
Jannis

Comment: don't use titlesec along with scrreport. Both don't like each other.

Comment: As for the counting, don't use the `*` forms of the `\chapter` etc. Use the normal forms, and `\renewcommand` the `\thechapter` counters and so on so that they are using the appropriate [counter style](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Counters#Counter_style).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer which package would you recommend then?

Comment: the KOMA classes have their  own tools, check the documentation (scrguide.pdf)

Comment: More specifically: chapter 21 section 8, page 480ish in the 2021-02-25 version of the documentation. If you want to use the KOMA script classes, you've gotta commit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you decided to move out of KOMA land, I can help now. :-)

You will have to fix the font sizes and spacing yourself. What I give you below hopefully will allow you to get started. See the interspersed comments for detailed explanations.

I will however point out the use of the `fmtcount` package: it provides a way to display ordinal numbers (in English: first, second third; in German: erste, zweite, ...) [see documentation for details on usage](https://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount?lang=en). I included this since you seemed to want the parts to be written as "Erster Teil" etc.

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, ngerman]{report}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fmtcount}  % The fmtcount package provides the \ordinalstring macro
        % use \Ordinalstring for capitalized version. 
        % There's also an optional argument to specify gender.  

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[center]{titlesec}


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}  % By default report only numbers to subsection
           % Need to add one more level to number subsubsection. 

% In your code you specified [display]; that does NOT reflect what you
% showed as the sample format you wish to recreate. I fixed it so now
% it uses [hang]
\titleformat{\part}[hang]  
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\ordinalstring{part} Part:}{0pt}{\large}
% note the use of \ordinalstring above
\titlespacing*{\part} 
  {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
  
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
    {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{0pt}{\large}
% It is better to put the period inside the \titleformat command
% rather than inside \thechapter, so that when cross referencing you 
% don't end up with spurious punctuation marks. 
% The numbers didn't show up in your version because you removed
% \thechapter, \thesection, etc from the \titleformat. Once 
% you restore them they show. 
\titlespacing*{\chapter} 
  {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
  
\titleformat{\section}[hang]
    {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection.}{0pt}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\section} 
  {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
  
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]
    {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{0pt}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\subsection} 
  {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
  
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]
        {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection)}{0pt}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection} 
  {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}


\titleclass{\part}{straight}
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}


\renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\alph{subsubsection}}
 % There is no need to define your all version of \alpha
 % Especially since now we placed the parenthesis inside the \titleformat



\begin{document}
\part{Test Paaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaart} 
  % The reason you didn't have line breaks earlier is because
  % latex doesn't know how to break the non-word paaaa.....art into 
  % parts and hyphenate. I added some spaces to show that line
  % breaking works as expected with the [hang] option

\bigskip


\chapter{Test Chapter}

\bigskip


\section{Test Section}

\bigskip


\subsection{Test Subsection}

\bigskip


\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}

\bigskip

{\lipsum[1-3]}
\end{document}
```

Compiled document
[image]

Edit:
I (questioner) have applied your suggestion, tweaked them a bit and added the indentation. Heres is the full answer:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, ngerman]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[center]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\titleformat{\part}[hang]  
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\Ordinalstring{part} Teil: }{0pt}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\part} 
  {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
  
\newcommand{\negphantom}[1]{\settowidth{\dimen0}{#1}\hspace*{-\dimen0}}
\newcommand{\SpacingA}{
    \hphantom{III.1.a)}\negphantom{xyzxy}
    }
\newcommand{\SpacingB}{
    \hphantom{A.III.1.a)}\negphantom{\Roman{section}.xyzxy}
    }
\newcommand{\SpacingC}{
    \hphantom{A.III.a)}\negphantom{xyzxy}
    }
\newcommand{\SpacingD}{
    \hphantom{A.III.1.}\negphantom{xyzxy}
    }

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
    {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thechapter.\SpacingA}{0pt}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\chapter} 
  {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
  
\titleformat{\section}[hang]
    {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection.\SpacingB}{0pt}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\section} 
  {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
  
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]
    {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection.\SpacingC}{0pt}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\subsection} 
  {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
  
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]
        {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection)\SpacingD}{0pt}{\large}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection} 
  {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\titleclass{\part}{straight}
\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}
\titleclass{\section}{straight}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\alph{subsubsection}}
```

compiled:

[image]